# Text line to JSON using Awk

Tags: json, awk, sed, text-processing

I have lines like this in a file.

```
Anywhere                   DENY IN     5.255.250.115              # Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
Anywhere                   DENY IN     46.229.168.153             # Sep 22 00:03:39 dn sshd[20969]: Bad protocol version identification \003 from port 64937
Anywhere                   DENY IN     213.180.203.49             # Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4 (compatible; YandexMobileBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)
```

I would like to transform these and only pull out the ip address and the comment at the end of each line.

Here is what i have so far:

```
grep 'DENY IN' tmp.txt | awk '{printf "{\"ip\":\"%s\",\"reason\":\"%s\"},", $4, substr($0,index($0,$5))}' | sed 's/,$//g' | awk '{ printf "[%s]", $0}'
[{"ip":"5.255.250.115","reason":"# Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"},{"ip":"46.229.168.153","reason":"# Sep 22 00:03:39 dn sshd[20969]: Bad protocol version identification \003 from port 64347"},{"ip":"213.180.203.49","reason":"# Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Versi"}]
```

The issue is that the comment string is not a valid json value.

When i feed that to python3 -m json.tool, i get this error:

```
grep 'DENY IN' tmp.txt | awk '{printf "{\"ip\":\"%s\",\"reason\":\"%s\"},", $4, substr($0,index($0,$5))}' | sed 's/,$//g' | awk '{ printf "[%s]", $0}' | python3 -m json.tool
Invalid \escape: line 1 column 218 (char 217)
```

Here is the expected result which I was able to get by writing a short python script:

```
[
    {
        "ip": "5.255.250.115",
        "reason": "# Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)\n"
    },
    {
        "ip": "46.229.168.153",
        "reason": "Sep 22 00:03:39 dn sshd[20969]: Bad protocol version identification \\003 from port 64937\n"
    },
    {
        "ip": "213.180.203.49",
        "reason": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4 (compatible; YandexMobileBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)\n"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to print the json value as an escaped literal string in the json output using Awk or any other command line tool? Kind of like python does when using json.dumps. Since i won't know what is in the comment value.

Here is the python script i used to get the desired output:

```
import sys
import json

json_arr = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line_parts = line.split(" ")
    json_obj = {'ip':line_parts[25],'reason':' '.join(line_parts[39:])}
    json_arr.append(json_obj)

print(json.dumps(json_arr, indent=4))
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not the "comment" what makes this break but the unescaped backslash in `\003`. It  needs to be escaped as `\\003` in order to be (part of) a valid JSON string.

Comment: I see, so i guess my question is if awk or jq has a filter which escapes all escapable characters kinda like printf "%q"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. Also state if the comments are REALLY split across multiple lines (e.g. resulting in `7` on it's own line in your shown input) or fix the input if that's not the case.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, i added more information and context

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? As `jq` is tagged, this reads each line as raw string using `-R`, `splits` the line by at least two consecutive spaces, and generates the object from the last two columns:

```sh
jq -nR '[inputs | [splits("\\s{2,}")] | {ip:.[2], reason:.[3]}]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "5.255.250.115",
    "reason": "# Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
  },
  {
    "ip": "46.229.168.153",
    "reason": "# Sep 22 00:03:39 dn sshd[20969]: Bad protocol version identification \\003 from port 64937"
  },
  {
    "ip": "213.180.203.49",
    "reason": "# Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4 (compatible; YandexMobileBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WZDteMyHGl)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to not return the first line though. Is that on purpose. I played around with the indexes but it doesn't seem to make the first line show up in the resulting JSON.

Comment: @Dan The `-n` option was missing which is needed with `inputs` to include the first item. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks again, but when i tried it with my other file it seems to put the Anywhere in the ip field. Which is a bit strange Maybe i will just whip up python for this.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk`-only solution - not as elegant as i hoped :

```
echo "${bbbbb}" \
\
| mawk '
  BEGIN {
     OFS = "\42, \42reason\42: \42"
      FS = "[ \\t][ \\t]+([\43][ ])?"
               _="[A]?[^D]+DENY[ ]IN[^0-9]+"
      RS = "^"(_)"|[\\r]?[\\n]("(_)")?"
  
        printf("[") } !NF { 
                            next 
  } !/(port [0-9]+|[)])$/ { 
  
       $_=sprintf("%s%*s",$_,(getline)^+RS,$_) 
  } { 
       gsub(/[\03]/, "\\003")
       gsub(/[\\]/,  "\\\\&")

       printf("%.*s{ \42ip\42: \42%s\42 }",
                  +_<__++, ",", $!(NF=NF)) 
  
  } END { printf("]\n") }' | jq

[
  {
    "ip": "5.255.250.115",
    "reason": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
  },
  {
    "ip": "46.229.168.153",
    "reason": "Sep 22 00:03:39 dn sshd[20969]: Bad protocol version identification &003 from port 6493"
  },
  {
    "ip": "213.180.203.49",
    "reason": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4 (compatible; YandexMobileBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
  }
]
```